# Replace all hyperlinks with file path name "\Name\" then add the TextToDisplay to the End of the Path "\Name\TextToDisplay"

Tags: vba, ms-word, hyperlink

I am in the process of trying to convert all hyperlinks (ex. https://drive.google.com/file/XXXX) in a Word document to local folder paths where the files will be housed. All the text to display (friendly name) match the file names accordingly in the local folder. All I would just need to do is have text to display be added to the end of said hyper/pathlink.

```
Sub HyperlinktoPath()
    Dim doc As Document
    Dim link, i

    'Loop through all open documents.
    For Each doc In Application.Documents
        'Loop through all hyperlinks.
        For i = 1 To doc.Hyperlinks.Count
            'If the hyperlink matches.
            If LCase(doc.Hyperlinks(i).Address) Like "https://drive.google.com/file/*" Then
                'Change the links address. Used wildcards (*) on either side.
                doc.Hyperlinks(i).Address = "\Evidence Folder\"
                'Change the links display text if desired.
            End If
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

I can't seem to figure out how to add the `TextToDisplay` to the end of the `"\Evidence Folder\ "` as if I was trying to do a concatenate `=concatenate("\Evidence Folder\",.TextToDisplay)` function on Excel, except this is for Word.

Comment: The most common way to concatenate in VBA is to use the `&` operator. Try `"\Evidence Folder\" & doc.Hyperlinks(i).TextToDisplay`

Comment: @SuperSymmetry Awesome!! Thank you this fixed it!